# Recover Apple CoreStorage Volume, LVG, Logical Volume Group -container / partition / volume

Tags: macos, partition, apfs, diskutil, recovery-hd

I wasn’t able to mount the disk on my MacBook (I had removed both hard drives from iMac, since it’s logic board went bad and I thought not to put more money on Apple products due to such bad hardware performances that I recently experienced for 2015 iMac and 2018 MacBook Pro).

So for data recovery from Harddrive and make it mountable after I connected both on my MacBook Pro from thunderbolt ports using their apdaters:

1. I create a coreStorage named FUSION using "**diskutil coreStorage create FUSION /dev/disk2 /dev/disk3**". i.e. disk2 - 128GB and disk3 - 2TB
2. It looked good, So I thought of shortcut by simply trying "First Aid" on diskutil for the drive to be able to make Drive mountable.
3. It ran without error but  it created an empty new volume of total 2TB and I wasn’t able to see any of my old files in it.
4. So upon try to undo this FUSION volume, I accidentally ran "**diskutil cs deleteLVG [Logical volume Group guid id]**".
5. Now I do not want to perform any thing unless I make sure I am right and restore the container and partitions that existed.

Anyone can please help me with good suggestion to restore my partition and make my disk mountable?

Comment: Just to be clear - you are trying to recover data from this system and don’t have a backup? (On step 2 did you repair or check) I’ll let someone ask for `gpt` or `diskutil` list if your goal isn’t to erase and make it ready to install again.

Comment: Yes I am trying to recover data but wouldn’t call it a system since I have both it’s hard drive outside iMac and  connecting as external hard drive to my MacBook.

Comment: On Step 2 I just ran Disk Utility GUI tool from masOS, it offer this FirstAid button. Which was just suppose to fix it but just more than that by formatting it without warning me. And whatever command from terminal in MacOS  can help me to mount the drive after restoring the disk’s container and or volume to be able to browse it with folder structure is the one I am more interested to explore. Thanks

Comment: Oh dear, repair makes the filesystem clean at the expense of data. I would get a professional quote before proceeding. Drive Savers is good.

Comment: Backup your drive and try Disk Drill to recover, perhaps?

Comment: Thank you. I am checking R-Studio, Recovery Explorer Professional, StellarDataRecovery, DiskDrill. Trying to see what's best and offer better option including performance. But still hoping to see how I can make it mountable. I might continue doing it even after I was able to backup with gpt command to fDisk and explorer other options later if possible. Anyone having any suggestion to restore LVG might help me.